# addEventListener Error.. Would some1 help me?

Tags: javascript

I added an event listener for my button element but it is not firing as expected.

The following is what I have tried so far:

```
var Button = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");

var bButton = document.getElementsByClassName ("buttons2");

var cButton = document.querySelector ("#inputNew");


Button.addEventListener("click", function (random){
    alert ("clicked") });
```

Comment: You can't add addEventListener to `getElementsByClassName`, it can returns more than 1 element, you need to do `Array.from(Button).forEach(button => button.addEventListener(...));`

Comment: You should use getElementById as the function you are using could give more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't return a single element but returns a collection of elements as a ***NodeList Object*** which you'll need to loop through each one of them using say, `forEach`.

However, if your buttons have separate class names, you should just use `querySelector` instead like this:

```
var aButton = document.querySelector("buttons");

var bButton = document.querySelector("buttons2");

var cButton = document.querySelector("#inputNew");

aButton.addEventListener("click", function (random){ alert ("clicked") });
bButton.addEventListener("click", function (random){ alert ("clicked") });
cButton.addEventListener("click", function (random){ alert ("clicked") });
```